# React / Rails API Image Uploading

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5, react-dropzone

I've built a React frontend along with a Rails API only backend. I want to allow the user to create a task and enter a title, description and upload an image.

So I've attempted to use DropZone to get access to the image and then send the image info along with the title and description to my Rails API via a post request using Axios.

I set up Carrierwave on my Rails API in hopes of uploading to an AWS S3 bucket once my Task has been added to the database per the post request.

None of this is working so my question is, should I take care of the image uploading to AWS on the react side and if so, how do I associate that image with the additional information I'm saving to my Rails database (title and description).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, on React side, there should be no proble with title and description, but for image, you need to encode the image to Base64 string. It is something like this.

```
getBase64 = (callback) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      console.log(fileReader.result);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
      console.log('Error :', error);
    };
}
```

Then, on Axios, send those 3 parameters alltogether with one POST request.

For Rails, you need to set up code that can read the Base64 string. Usually, you can use `Paperclip` or `CarrierWave`gem to add image attachment. It will look like this.

```
property_image = listing.property_images.new(param_image)

if param_image[:file_data]
  image_file = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(param_image[:file_data])
  image_file.original_filename = param_image[:image_file_name]
  image_file.content_type = "image/png"
  property_image.image = image_file
end

private

def param_image
  params.permit(:image, :image_file_name, :file_data)
end
```